# Show that two random variables are independent.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, gamma-function

Let $X \simeq \Gamma(a,1)$ and $Y \simeq \Gamma(b,1)$ be independent. Show that $U = X +Y$ and $V = X/(X +Y)$ are independent and find their distributions.

How would you do this for $U$ and $V$, do you use the Jacobian matrix transform to prove this?  Additionally, when you're finding their distributions are you looking for the joint distributions of $U$ and $V$ or the distribution of $U$ and the distribution of $V$?

Comment: Yes, you find the inverse transform, its Jacobian, and express the (joint!) density of the variables is terms of them. They are independent iff the joint density factors: $p(x,y) = g(x) h(y)$.

Comment: What exactly would the Jacobian tell us?

Comment: It is written in your textbook.